# Newtonsoft Json Deserialization: Selective Date Parsing

Tags: json.net

I'm trying to selectively parse (only certain and not all) valid date strings  into DateTimeOffset during deserialization. Has anyone achieved that?

Here's the Json I'm trying to deseralize into a JObject:

```
{
  "SomeDate": "2019-09-19T01:21:00.747Z",
  "SomeString": "2019-09-19T01:21:00.747Z"
}
```

Here's the deserializer I'm using:

```
JsonSerializer Deserializer = new JsonSerializer
        {
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset
        };
```

As you can expect, here's the JObject I get back:

```
{
  "SomeDate": "2019-09-19T01:21:00.747+00:00",
  "SomeString": "2019-09-19T01:21:00.747+00:00"
}
```

But I'd like to deserialize only SomeDate into a DateTimeOffset and retain SomeString as is:

```
{
  "SomeDate": "2019-09-19T01:21:00.747+00:00",
  "SomeString": "2019-09-19T01:21:00.747Z"
}
```

I can't decorate SomeString property with a custom converter since I'm deserializing to a JObject and therefore I don't have a class to put the decorator

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want the behavior to be dependent on the serialized value.

If so, you may have to provide your own serializer. See: https://blog.kulman.sk/custom-datetime-deserialization-with-json-net/

```cs
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    if (reader.Value == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var s = reader.Value.ToString();

    if (s.Contains("+"))
    {
        // DateTimeOffset
    }
    else
    {
        // DateTime
    }
}
```

Once you do that, you can register it as a serializer setting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want the behavior to be dependent on the serialized value. In my case, the serialized value is exactly the same for both the DateTimeOffset case and the String case. I just want to be selective (based on the property) during deserialization. I want to deserialize the value into DateTimeOffset in one case and into a string (even though it's a valid date string) in the other case

Comment: Is this behavior something that is known statically? e.g. if key has date, then convert to `DateTimeOffset`, else convert to `string`? If it is not, then I don't know how you would determine whether or not the value should be treated as one type or another.

Comment: The static information that we have is ```SomeString```'s value should never be interpreted into anything else. No matter what value it has, it should be retained as is. So I'm basically looking for a way to instruct the Json parser to not try to convert ```SomeString```'s value into a date or anything else for that matter

Comment: I'm ok with the Json parser trying to convert ```SomeDate```'s value into a date. In fact, that's what I want (I achieve this by using a setting as you can see in my original post). I just don't want the same behavior for ```SomeString```.

Comment: How do you plan on using it? Can you provide a code sample that shows what it is currently doing and what you would like it to do? FYI, I find it helps if you use https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and share the link.